# Discrete mathematics - Find all integer solutions of the equation $a^2+ b^2 + c^2=a^2 b^2$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Find all integer solutions of the equation $a^2+ b^2 + c^2=a^2 b^2$.

This is one of the questions we presented in one session to contest preparation PUTNAM. It turns out that I can't get from the problem. Could someone just give me a hint? (Please, don't give me the answer. Simply, an argument that can help me advance in the problem or theorem might suffice.)

Comment: I would write $1 + c^2 = (a^2 - 1)(b^2 - 1)$ because there are rules about what kinds of numbers (and primes in particular) are allowed to divide $1+c^2$

Comment: 1. I would first observe the obvious answer
2. Off my intuition, this will involve infinite descent. (I don't know if it actually does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation is equivalent to
$$
c^2+1=(a^2-1)(b^2-1)
$$
Since the left side is either $1$ or $2$ mod $4$, and the right side is either $0$ or $1$ mod $4$, they must both be $1$ mod $4$, which means that $a,b,c$ must be even.

Since any prime which is $3$ mod $4$ is a Gaussian prime, no prime which is $3$ mod $4$ can divide $c^2+1=(c+i)(c-i)$. Thus, the only primes which can divide $c^2+1$ must be $1$ mod $4$.

Since $a^2-1$ and $b^2-1$ are both $3$ mod $4$, they must have a prime factor which is $3$ mod $4$ and hence cannot divide the left hand side (except if they are both $-1$). Thus, the only solution is when $a,b,c=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some hints.

Case $1$: $a$ or $b$ is even.

Then RHS $\equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Then we get that the LHS is also $0 \pmod 4$. The LHS will be a sum of one square or two squares modulo $4$ in this case. This forces all of $a,b,c$ to be even since the quadratic residues modulo $4$ are either $0$ or $1$. Thus, unless all $a,b,c$ are $0$, we can divide out the powers of $2$ to get to case $2$.

Case $2$: Both $a,b$ are odd.

Then RHS is $1 \pmod 4$ and LHS is $2+c^2 \pmod 4$. This equation is impossible.

Thus the only solution is $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Case 1: If you divide $a,b,c$ by $2$, that divides the left by $4$ and the right by $16$. Then the equation no longer holds.

Comment: I have a bit of difficulties to understand  what means " Thus, unless all a,b,c  are 0 , we can divide out the powers of 2  to get to case 2 ". Could you explain a bit?